# How does fastCGI PHP alter a file and escape detection by auditd?

Tags: php, security, debian, auditd

The other day I set up a little shell script on a Debian server to send me an email when files change; it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

items=`find /var/www/vhosts -regex ".*/httpdocs/.*" -newer files_start -ls`
if [ ! -z "$items" ]
then
 touch files_start
 echo "$items" | mail -s "new file(s)" "security@example.com"
fi
```

I kept getting notified of one mysterious 0-length text file (web-accessible, writable by PHP and the vhost user, but not Apache) getting modified 2-3 times a day, so I set up auditd with the following rule.

```
auditctl -l
LIST_RULES: exit,always watch=/var/www/vhosts/path/to/file.txt perm=rwa key=wh1
```

I tested it and with ausearch got, as expected:

```
...comm="touch" exe="/bin/touch"...
```

After getting the next email with the new mod date, I ran ausearch: no new matches!

How can this happen?

----UPDATE----

I discovered by other means that the process is PHP running as fastCGI invoked by Apache. The PHP function call is:

```
touch('path/to/file.txt');
```

So the question becomes: How does fastCGI PHP alter a file and escape detection by auditd? This is beginning to look like an auditd bug.

Answer (score 0):

Delete that rule and try this:

```
auditctl -w <path-to-file> -p wa -k mystery-file
```

Also make sure /etc/init.d/auditd is started.

Comment: Thanks for the answer fenix, but that's essentially the auditctl call that generated the rule listed by auditctl -l, and auditd is definitely running. Any time I touch or cp or rm or ls or do anything to that file I get a log entry that shows up in ausearch.